# Populate cells of worksheet with 500+ column headers from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to populate Cells A1 to Z1 then A2 to Z2 on a worksheet called "Main" with the values of the headers in row 1 from a worksheet called "PPL". The number of columns is variable but will be 500+.

```
    Sub Button1_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_Button1

    Dim SourceCol As Integer, DestCol As Integer, DestRow As Integer
    SourceCol = 1
    DestCol = 1
    DestRow = 1

    Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("PPL").Cells(1, SourceCol))
    Do Until DestCol = 26
    Worksheets("Main").Select
    Worksheets("Main").Cells(DestRow, DestCol).Value = Strip(Worksheets("PPL").Cells(1, SourceCol).Value)
    DestCol = DestCol + 1
    SourceCol = SourceCol + 1
    Loop
    DestCol = 1
    DestRow = DestRow + 1
    Loop
    Exit Sub

Err_Button1:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number

End Sub
Private Function Strip(Value As String) As String
    Strip = Replace(Value, "_", " ")
End Function
```

Comment: You won't get great feedback here w/o showing you mad at least an attempt. Also you're descriptions is a bit lacking, maybe add 2 sample sheet images so people can understand what exactly it is you're looking to do? In general I'd say have a look at `copy` and `pastespecial` and maybe `transpose` to flip the values in your row to a column

Comment: You're going to need a loop probably. However, what you have written here is very unclear and no one will be able to discern what it is you're actually asking. Try some stuff out, get a few attempts in then come back with your attempts so we can work off of those.

Comment: put this in A1 on the Main sheet: `=INDEX(Part!$1:$1,(ROW(1:1)-1)*26+(COLUMN(A:A)-1)+1)` copy over to column Z and down the number of rows needed.

Comment: @Nick Have you signed an NDA? Are you seriously suggesting that people give away company secrets on here? I have tried to explain as carefully as I can without breaking company rules. But as you are accepting that NDA and Security rules be broken. I have included an attempt I tried. And please note that your down-voting of this question before any explanation does not hold StackOverflow is good light for future questions.

Comment: And to clarify. The sheet Part has 500+ columns with a header on the first row. I need to hide those unimportant columns and to do this, I need to make a sheet called Main with all the headers listed so that a double click will hide those columns and make searching the Parts table easier to view on a laptop screen. Does that explain things a little better?

Comment: @lonewolf so a) I didn't downvote this post  b)  i wrote attaching *sample* sheets, as in sheets showing the general format of your data not it's contents. So no, I do not suggest to release sensitive information. Glad you found somebosy to help you out though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scotts' answer is a good formula, here is a basic VBA example: comments within  the code, update sheet names as needed

Copy the below code and paste into the Visual Basic Editor window

```
Sub SplitRowIntoMultipleRows()

Dim srcews As Worksheet, destws As Worksheet, lCol As Long, i As Long 'Declare the variables

    'Assign your variables
    Set srcews = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Part")
    Set destws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

    lCol = srcews.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    x = 1 'increment the rows in the destws 'Loop thru the row 1 in the srcews incrementing every 26 cells

        For i = 1 To lCol Step 26 

           'Copy every 26 cells in row 1 of the srcews and paste to the destws,
           'starting in Cells(1,1), and stepping to the next row for each loop 

           srcews.Cells(1, i).Resize(, 26).Copy destws.Cells(x, 1)

           x = x + 1 'add 1 to start on the next row in the destws

        Next i 'loop to the next cel, whic would be `Cells(1, 27)`, etc.
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you GMalc. I knew someone would understand what was written.

Comment: @Lonewolf Your welcome; I was surprised to get a comment to an answer I gave in July, I'm glad I could help you.